# Invoking the rate module in views template file doesn't work

Tags: 7, views, rating

I have installed both the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) modules. In the views-view-fields.tpl.php file, I put the following code.

```
$node = node_load($row->nid);   
echo $node->content['rate_poll']['#value'];
echo $node->title;
```

There is no output for `$node->content['rate_poll']['#value']`, while the code outputs the node title. Why?

How can I output `$node->content['rate_poll']['#value']` in views-view-fields.tpl.php, or other Views files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote doesn't work because `$node->content['rate_poll']['#value']` is only present when the node is being viewed. The code that adds `$node->content['rate_poll']['#value']` is in the implementation of `hook_nodeapi()`, and the code is executed when the operation is "view."

```
/**
 * Implements hook_nodeapi().
 */
function rate_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3, $a4) {
  // Adding the form to the node view
  if ($op == 'view') {
    $widgets = rate_get_active_widgets('node', $node->type, $a3);

    foreach ($widgets as $widget_id => $widget) {
      $widget_name = 'rate_' . $widget->name;
      _rate_check_widget($widget);

      $display_mode = $a3 ? $widget->teaser_display_mode : $widget->node_display_mode;

      $widget_code = array(
        '#value' => rate_generate_widget($widget_id, 'node', $node->nid, $display_mode),
        '#weight' => $widget->node_display == RATE_DISPLAY_ABOVE_CONTENT ? 0 : 50,
      );

      if ($widget->node_display != RATE_DISPLAY_ABOVE_CONTENT && $widget->node_display != RATE_DISPLAY_BELOW_CONTENT) {
        $node->$widget_name = $widget_code;
      }
      else {
        $node->content[$widget_name] = $widget_code;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the code to work, you should change it to the following one.

```
$node = node_load($row->nid);
node_invoke_nodeapi($node, 'view', FALSE, TRUE);
echo $node->content['rate_poll']['#value'];
echo $node->title;
```

[node_invoke_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_invoke_nodeapi/6) invokes any implementation of `hook_nodeapi()`, using its first parameter as operation value. Once the function returns, `$node` will contain any `$node->content` value added by the modules, including `$node->content['rate_poll']['#value']`.

Comment: you're my hero! i have thought this problem long time.many many thanks.